# What is "my_main()" in the code

Tags: c

I've seen code like below in a project:

```
extern void my_main(void) __attribute__ ((__noreturn__, asection(".main","f=ax")));
```

What does this do?

The project does not have a direct `main()` function in it. Does the above code indicate to the compiler that `my_main()` should be treated as `main()`?

Also, what does the `.main` memory section indicate?

Comment: Could you please state the compiler/ide used?

Comment: This is hard to anser without knowing more about the platform your are using/programming.

Comment: it is a void function declared with attributes of function. [Read here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

Comment: @Superlokkus most likely GCC/CLang. MSVC doesn't have `__attribute__`.

Comment: Compiler used is /gnu/gcc/gcc-4.6.3. The code shown above is a declaration from a header file and the actual function call will be in a *.c file like `my_main(void)`.

Answer (score 3):

What the above declaration basically does is declare an `extern` function called `my_main()` with no arguments.

The `__attribute__` section is a GNU/LLVM [attribute syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html). Attributes are basically pragmas that describe some non-standard or extended feature of the function in question - in this case, `my_main()`.

---

There are two attributes applied to `my_main()`.

[`__noreturn__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) (search for `noreturn`) indicates that the function will *never* return.

This is different from returning `void` - in `void`-type functions, calls to the function still `return` at some point, even without a value. This means execution will jump/return back to the caller.

In `noreturn` (a.k.a. `_noreturn` or `__noreturn__`) functions, this indicates that, among other things, calls to this function shouldn't add the return address to the stack, as the function itself will either exit before execution returns, or will long jump to another point in execution.

It is also used in places where adding the return address to the stack will disrupt the stack in a way that interferes with the called function (though this is rare and I've only ever seen it used for this reason once).

---

The second attribute, `asection(".main","f=ax")`, is a little more vague. I can't seem to find specific documentation for it, but it seems more or less pretty straightforward.

What it appears to be doing is specifying a [linker section](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html) as well as what *appears* to be a [unix filemode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Symbolic_modes) specifying that the resulting binary is e**x**ecutable, though I could be wrong.

---

When you write native code, all functionality is placed into appropriate sections of the target binary format (e.g. ELF, Mach-O, PE, etc.) The most common sections are `.text`, `.rodata`, and `.data`.

However, when invoking `ld`, the GCC linker, you can specify a [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html) to specify *exactly* how you want the target binary to be constructed.

This includes sections, sizes, and even the object files you want to use to make the file, specifying where they should go and their size limits.

One common misconception is that you never use `ld`. This isn't the case; when you run `gcc` or `g++` or the `clang`-family of compilers without the `-c` flag, you inadvertently invoke `ld` with a [default linker script](http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-default-linker-script-used-by-gcc-td141145.html) used to link your binaries.

Linker scripts are important especially for embedded hardware where ROM must be built to memory specification.

---

So back to your line of code: it places `my_func()` into an arbitrary section called `.main`. That's all it does. Ultimately, somewhere in your project, there is a linker script that specifies how `.main` is used and where it goes.

I would imagine the goal of this code was to place `my_main()` at an *exact* address in the target binary/executable, so whatever is using it knows the exact location of that function (`asection(".main")`) and can use it as an entry point (`__noreturn__`).

Comment: Hopefully this helps. I can explain a bit better if necessary, as you actually asked a few questions in one!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Generally for a project one `main()` should be present. But here in this project I can see only this `my_main()`. I am not clear that `.main` section will make `my_main()` as `main()`